# Social Network integration

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

When I was strolling [Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/), I noticed that they seem to have a twitter bot: [On Biology.SE](https://biology.stackexchange.com/posts/1343/revisions) (See the middle event), [on Twitter](https://twitter.com/#!/StackBiology/).

I would be willing to dive into a bit of Python and Stack Exchange / Twitter API to build a bot for RPG.SE, or just take a look at [StackApps](https://stackapps.com/) (Where I guess there are already some such bots) and run such a bot on my home server, if the majority thinks that this would be a good thing.

Opinions?

Comment: Delete if you want to keep this tidy, I'll leave it for future reference (As I found no link to the twitter account on the site).

Comment: you should move your "Never Mind" into an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suggested by @WaxEagle, I'm moving this into an answer:

[We already have such a twitter account](https://twitter.com/#!/StackRPG/), it just seems like it's not advertised anywhere on the website.

Comment: good find, followed!