# How does the bot choose Q&A to publish on Twitter?

Tags: discussion

I already saw some of my questions being tweeted on the [RPG Stack Exchange](https://twitter.com/StackRPG/) Twitter account.

At first, I though Q&A were put on Twitter when someone, like a moderator, find it good and interesting.

When I started to read other's question's edit, I also saw these "tweeted notification" and sometimes give a look at the tweeter to find good Q&A to read.

Only recently I noticed that Q&A are posted every 3 hours, so it's obviously a bot doing it (I guess the mods are busy enough to not have to use Buffer and other tools that let you schedule tweets).

As a software developer, I'm pretty curious about **how the bot chooses which Q&A is going to be tweeted**, what's the algorithm behind it (maybe it's just the most viewed last 3 hours and that's all).

**Does anyone know?**

Comment: [Here's a related question about this exact bot](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1372/social-network-integration) (by someone who didn't know it existed at the time). And a basically identical question from MSE, the overall network meta: [How does the twitter bot work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work)

Comment: @V2Blast Yup, that is pretty much the only question in meta about this bot. Sadly, nothing useful for my curiosity in this one :/ Looks like this poor forgotten bot is a background worker ([dev joke I guess](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1290103/10979590)).

Comment: I edited in another link to a question on MSE that you may find to be of use.

Comment: @V2Blast Oh, it's exactly what I was looking for, thank you. So this Q&A is kind of a dupe? Should I delete it or make an answer linking the other question?

Comment: I'd suggest writing an answer citing/quoting that information, if you feel it answers your question :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thanks To [@V2Blast ♦](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/users/33569/v2blast) comment, I found an answer to my question in [this MSE Q&A about the twitter bot](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183407/how-does-the-twitter-bot-work).

In [the accepted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183410/464583), it is told based on [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/464583) (link-ception) that the twitter bot use an algorithm to determine which Q&A is "hot" (don't know if it is the same as the one used to determine [Hot Network Questions](https://stackexchange.com/questions?tab=hot)).

This algorithm calculation is based on views in a short time period (and maybe other points).

Additionally, there are some restrictions that may prevent a "hot" Q&A to be tweeted :

- The score of the Question has to be more or equal to 1<sup>1</sup>
- The Question must not have any close vote (probably same for flag<sup>2</sup>)
- The Q&A can be tweeted even if there's a close vote (again, maybe same for flag) on the Question if there is a bounty for this Q&A<sup>3</sup>.

I guess there might be more restrictions, but that is all I managed to find.

---

<sup>1</sup> : [@Nick Craver ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) announced this limit has been set from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94593/464583)

<sup>2</sup> : In [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899/464583), [@Nick Craver ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) announces that Question with close vote will not be tweeted anymore. It is asked in comment for the flag case, but he didn't reply to it.

<sup>3</sup> : In [this same answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/115899/464583), [@Nick Craver ♦](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/135201/nick-craver) indicate that Question with bounty have survived enough time to get a bounty, so even a close vote might not be a problem here.